# Simultaneous rotation, translation, and scaling of bitmap in android canvas

Tags: android, matrix, android-canvas

I'm trying to show a picture, which can be zoomed and panned, and that rotates with a compass reading. With the code below, all three actions kind of work, but they influence each other.

Here is what I want to achieve:
1. Rotate around the center of the screen
2. Scale leaving the same part of the picture in the center
3. Pan to the desired spot in the picture

Here is what is actually happening with the code below:
1. Rotation works as intended, around the center of the screen
2. Scaling works, but it scales around the *center of the picture*
3. Translation only works as intended if `angle` is zero, otherwise it's moving in a wrong direction

```
// the center of the view port
float centerX = screen.right/2;
float centerY = screen.bottom/2;

Matrix m = new Matrix();
m.preRotate(angle, centerX, centerY);
m.preScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, centerX, centerY);

// scaling the amount of translation, 
// rotating the translation here gave crazy results
float x = mPosX / mScaleFactor;
float y = mPosY / mScaleFactor;
m.preTranslate(x, y);

canvas.drawBitmap(pic, m, null);
```

If I translate first, and later rotate, the translation works as intended but the rotation is not around the center of the view port anymore.

How can I apply all three transformations, without them influencing each other?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the scaling around the centre of the image, but as for the translation being in the wrong direction is it not as a consequence of you rotating the image but not the translations? Maybe try something like this:

```
float x = (mPosX*(cos(angle) + sin(angle)) / mScaleFactor;
float y = (mPosY*(cos(angle) - sin(angle)) / mScaleFactor;
m.preTranslate(x, y);
```

Also does the matrix object have a method to apply an [affine transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Affine_transformations) directly? Because then you won't need to think about the order of operations.

The affine transformation might look something like this:

```
M = |mScaleFactor*cos(angle)       sin(angle)            x|
    |     -sin(angle)          mScaleFactor*cos(angle)   y|
    |          0                         0               1|
```

But this will rotate around the corner of the image so you need to use the preTranslate() function first like so:

```
Mt.preTranslate(-centerX,-centerY);
```

And APPLY Mt to pic before applying M and then after you need to apply -Mt

Comment: Rotating the translation appears to just offset the rotation, but I also have the feeling that this is what I need. Android matrices are 3x3, so I guess they already are affine transformations?

Comment: So maybe try setting the matrix directly instead of using those preRotate, preScale methods? So your matrix should be something like the edit in the post above

Comment: With this matrix, panning works, but scaling also rotates the picture, rotation also scales the pic, and rotation happens around a corner of the picture. It's like whac-a-mole, but thanks for your input.

Comment: The scaling and rotation should def not interfere with each other, that's weird, have you tried it with and angle of 0? Or with an angle but with mScaleFactor = 1? As for the rotation around the corner, that makes sense, I'll edit again.

Comment: Scaling and rotating only work without interference if either mScaleFactor=1 or angle=0. Otherwise I think a single matrix with the right values is the right way to solve this problem.